# Issue with facebook android app and SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-app-requests

I am developing an app for android. I am using the long lived access token. I use the following code to send app requests to facebook:

//code showing relevant sections.

```
private WeakReference<FragmentActivity> mActivity;
mActivity = new WeakReference<FragmentActivity>(activity);
private Facebook mFacebook; //mFacebook is Facebook object and contains session info
mActivity.get() //Gets the current context
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message","App request message");

mFacebook.dialog(mActivity.get(), "apprequests", params, new AppRequestsListener());
```

Now, this request is failing with API error 10, if facebook app is installed on the phone. If I remove the facebook app from phone, this request starts working.

Is it a known issue with facebook based apps on android?

Regards
Ajay

Comment: Can you post more information such as what you are trying to do, what `DialogKeys` is, what `mActivity.get()` is, and also any stack trace or logcat relevant to this issue?

Comment: I hace added relevant sections to explain the call better.

Answer (score 0):

For Login call, we are now forcing the Web Dialog (ignore installed app). once we do this, even for app requests, we get web dialog (and not native app dialog)